# \newcommand Tikz argument problem

Tags: pgfplots

I have this two commands to read x from y or y from x on a plot.

The problem is that the label is 180:#3 with above position instread of #3 east position.

The wish (less important) : how to merge the two commands in one ?

```
\newcommand{\ReadY}[3][180]{%
    \draw[very thin, dashed] (axis cs:#2,0)|-(axis cs:0,#3) coordinate (Y) ;
    \node[small dot,pin=#1:#3] at (Y) {};
}

\newcommand{\ReadX}[3][270]{%
    \draw[very thin, dashed] (axis cs:0,#2)-|(axis cs:#3,0) coordinate (Y) ;
    \node[small dot,pin=#1:#3] at (Y) {};
}
```

Has to be corrected to :

```
\newcommand{\ReadY}[3][180]{%
    \draw[very thin, dashed] (axis cs:#2,0)|-(axis cs:0,#3) coordinate (Y) ;
    \node[small dot,pin={[pin position={#1}]{#3}}] at (Y) {};
}

\newcommand{\ReadX}[3][270]{%
    \draw[very thin, dashed] (axis cs:0,#2)-|(axis cs:#3,0) coordinate (Y) ;
    \node[small dot,pin={[pin position={#1}]{#3}}] at (Y) {};
}
```

Is it possible to merge the two command in one ?

I mean :

- the first argument is the optinal angle,
- the second is the value I know
- the third in the value give by the function and red on the plot (the image or the antecedent)

the label has to be on this node.

Minimal example :

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}

 % boite de couleur avec un filet autour
 \tikzset{%
     boxcolor/.style args={#1}{%
   fill=#1!25!white,rectangle,rounded corners=4pt,font=\footnotesize,draw=#1},
    small dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.3}}


\newcommand{\ReadY}[3][175]{%
    \draw[very thin, dashed] (axis cs:#2,0)|-(axis cs:0,#3) coordinate (Y) ;
    \node[small dot,pin={[boxcolor=green,pin position={#1}]{%
            \pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{#3}}}] at (Y) {};
}

\newcommand{\ReadX}[3][265]{%
    \draw[very thin, dashed] (axis cs:0,#2)-|(axis cs:#3,0) coordinate (Y) ;
    \node[small dot,pin={[boxcolor=green,pin position={#1}]{%
\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{#3}}}] at (Y) {};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=2,xmin=-2,ymin=-2,ymax=2,
axis x line=center, axis y line=center]
\node[below left] at (axis cs:0,0) {\footnotesize $0$};
\ReadX{.5}{.5} ;
\ReadY{1}{1.5} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Tahnks to Peter Grill, with more options and even en node to put something on the point itself :

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\ReadXY}{%
    D<>{green}% [#1] first color
    o%% [#2] = optional parameters x pin
        % (no x pin if no angle provided, which is the default)
    m%  % {#3} = x value (mandatory paramater)
    D<>{green}% [#4] second color
    o%% [#5] = optional parameters for y pin
        % (no y in if no angle provided, which is the default)
    m%  % {#6} = y value (mandatory paramater)
}{%
    \draw[very thin, dashed] (axis cs:#3,0) coordinate (ReadX)%
        |- (axis cs:0,#6) coordinate (ReadY) ;
    % new node on the point
    \coordinate (ReadXY) at (axis cs:#3,#6) ;
    %
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
        \node[small dot,pin={[boxcolor=#1,pin position={#2}]
            {\smash[b]{\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{#3}}}}] at (ReadX) {};
    }{}%
    %
    \IfValueTF{#5}{%
        \node[small dot,pin={[boxcolor=#4,pin position={#5}]
            {\smash[b]{\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{#6}}}}] at (ReadY) {};
    }{}%
}%
```

Comment: Can you please provide a *complete*, minimal document and not just snippets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I understand what you want, but this should give you an idea as to how to combine the commands into a single command.

The `\ReadXY` macro below has two optional parameters for the `x` and the `y` pin angle. If the angle is not specified that coordinate is not labelled. So, this one macro allows you to have four possible combinations:

- Label box `x` and `y`,
- Label *only* the `x`,
- Label *only* the `y`, and
- Label *neither* coordinate, but just draw the lines:

as illustrated here:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}

\tikzset{%
    boxcolor/.style args={#1}{%
    fill=#1!25!white,rectangle,rounded corners=4pt,font=\footnotesize,draw=#1},
    small dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.3}}


\NewDocumentCommand{\ReadXY}{%
    O{}% [#1] = optional parameters x pin (no x pin if no angle provided, which is the default)
    O{}% [#2] = optional parameters for y pin (no y pin if no angle provided, which is the default)
    m% {#3} = x value (mandatory paramater)
    m% {#4} = y value (mandatory paramater)
}{%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{}{}{%
        \draw[very thin, dashed] (axis cs:0,#4)-|(axis cs:#3,0) coordinate (Y) ;
        \node[small dot,pin={[boxcolor=green,pin position={#1}]
            {\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{#3}}}] at (Y) {};
    }%
    %
    \IfStrEq{#2}{}{}{%
        \draw[very thin, dashed] (axis cs:#3,0)|-(axis cs:0,#4) coordinate (Y) ;
        \node[small dot,pin={[boxcolor=green,pin position={#2}]
            {\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{#4}}}] at (Y) {};
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=2,xmin=-2,ymin=-2,ymax=2,axis x line=center, axis y line=center]
    \node[below left] at (axis cs:0,0) {\footnotesize $0$};
    \ReadXY[-120][-160]{0.75}{1.0};% <--- Label BOTH x and y
    \ReadXY[45][]{1.25}{1.4};% <--- Label ONLY x
    \ReadXY[][20]{-1.5}{-1.7};% <--- Label ONLY y
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not using `o` instead of `O{}` and `\IfNoValueTF{#1}` instead of `\IfStrEq{#1}{}`? I believe that it's better a sequence of arguments like `omom`, so the two optional arguments become independent of each other.

Comment: @egreg: That was my first version, but ran into difficulty when I want to _only_ supply the _second_ optional parameter, so have to specify it as `\ReadXY[][120]{}{}`. Now the first parameter can no longer be tested via `\IfNoValueTF{#1}`.

Comment: I do not know about \NewDocumentCommand etc. Thank's it works even better I thaught, with more possibilities.